# Fundamental PHP Variables

Tags: php, variables

I'm a little suprised, why this is happening?!

```
$test = "THE STRING";
if($test == 0) echo "WTF!?"; else echo "OK";
```

The output is:

```
WTF!?
```

In the upper line, we just made **$test** variable as string, why it's equal to **0** based by the example above!?

Thanks

Comment: That's because PHP is loose typed, read all about it in the docs http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - learn the benefits and the pitfalls (and how to avoid them)

Comment: @decze: No it is not, although the answers to both questions might be the same.

Comment: Because of the loose type casting, your == is attempting to compare your string with the numberic value 0. To make sure this can be calculated properly, it attempts to convert your string to an integer. Since its not a valid numeric value, it converts it to 0. === makes it enforce type checking. Since the 2 values are not the same "types" it automatically returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
===
```

for this. PHP uses this for strict comparison.

```
if($test === 0) {
    echo "WTF?"
} else {
    echo "OK!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if($test === 0){
    echo "WTF?"
} else {
    echo "OK!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead (with triple equal sign):

```
if($test === 0) echo "WTF!?"; else echo "OK";
```

Read [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for more information.